# Python: Homemade Tab Completion Help

Tags: python, command-line-interface, homebrew, tab-completion

I need some help.  I am completely stumped.  I'm trying to write my own tab completion module for a custom shell style program (also completing arguments) I can tab complete the commands, but the arguments are giving me trouble.  Can some one write a sample tab completing module for me to look at?
Available Commands:
['show','exit','clear', 'ship']
for command show, first arg:
['ip','mac','options']
and for sub arg IP:
['external,'internal','local']

In the end I want to be able to go:

```
My Prompt > sh<tab>
show ship
My Prompt > sho<tab>
My Prompt > show <tab>
ip mac options
My Prompt > show ip <tab>
external local internal
My Prompt > show ip e<tab>
My Prompt > show ip external
```

and so on an so forth.  If I just had one good working example I think I could figure this out.  I've completely rewritten my tab completion code 5 times, but still I can't get it.  Could some one please help?

Comment: Nobody is going to write your code for you for free, but if you post code you're having a specific problem with, you will probably see several ways to improve it.

Comment: Here you go: http://codepad.org/pnuHKkL8 Don't be too harsh, I just took up python on Wednesday, so I'm not yet familiar with all the nuances of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I figured it out after the 7th rewrite.  A little messier than I would like, but workable, likely I will clean this up later.  Anyways, here's the code:

```
"""defined earlier in the script:"""
COMMANDS=['show', 'exit', 'ship']
def complete(text, state, list = COMMANDS):
    for option in list:
        if option.startswith(text):
            if not state:
                return option
            else:
                state -= 1
def precomplete(text, state):
    BUFFER=readline.get_line_buffer()
    args=[None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None]
    argtemp=[]
    if BUFFER != "":
        i=-1
        while i != BUFFER.count(" "):
            if BUFFER.count(" ") >= 0:
                if BUFFER.count(" ") == 0: #1 because len() starts couting at 1
                    return complete(text, state)
                else:
                    print "Else triggered"
                    o=0
                    verb=[]
                    while complete(BUFFER.split()[0],o):
                        verb.append(complete(BUFFER.split()[0],o))
                        o=o+1
                    if len(verb) == 1:
                        verb=verb[0]
                        print verb
            if BUFFER.count(" ") >= 1:
                if  BUFFER.count(" ") == 1:
                    if verb == 'show':
                        return complete(text, state, ['mac', 'ip', 'arp'])
                else:
                    o=0
                    while complete(BUFFER[1],o,['mac', 'ip', 'arp']):
                        argtemp.append(complete(BUFFER[1],o,['mac', 'ip', 'arp']))
                        o=o+1
                    if len(argtemp) == 1:
                       argtemp==argtemp[0]
            i=i+1
    else:
        return complete(text,state)
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(precomplete)
```

EDIT: Full code:http://codepad.org/W3VHURUx

Answer (score 0):

Look at [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) and [rlcompleter](http://docs.python.org/library/rlcompleter.html).

Comment: I'm using readline, and that is working just fine, but rlcompleter does not appear to allow for custom commands (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @Trcx: You asked for a sample tab completion module. Take a look at the source for rlcompleter.

Comment: Source being where? I just picked up python and am not sure where to start looking.

Comment: @Tcrx: It's at the top of the page, [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/rlcompleter.py)

Comment: Thank you I'll be sure to check it out, but back to work now. :(

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in an existing implemention that does that in a general way.

The [CLI toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/#svn/trunk/CLI/pycopia) does command and some parameter completions. However, doing this well from Python turns out to be not entirely possible. This is mainly due to the readline library (running in compiled code) having control of user input at that time so you have to have all the completions known beforehand before calling into the input method.